# VPN to a subnet B via an ssh connection via connection A on the same server

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, vpn

I have a server at a remote location, which is on two subnets (i.e. it has two network interface cards NIC1 and NIC2, A is on e.g. 130.0.0.0, B is on 192.168.1.10). I can ssh in via A, which is outward facing.

How can I access resources in the subnet B from my home computer. E.g. I would like to access the switching hub of subnet B via its browser interface (192.168.1.0).

All machines are running Ubuntu 18.04.

I do not want to set up a VPN server on the remote machine (for security reasons). I would prefer to do everything over my existing SSH tunnel.

I know that I have previously been able to create a tun interface on my local (home) computer via ssh, using sshuttle:

```
sshuttle -r user@remoteserver 0.0.0.0/0 -vv --dns
```

However, this will direct my HTTP and HTTPS requests through the "normal" gateway of the remote server (I.e. I will access the internet normally with my IP showing up as the server's IP).

I want to go via the subnet B (to access via browser the switching hub's network interface).

Is there a direct way to do this or do I need to go about this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to actually get this working using the original idea I had, with one trick: I had to enable ufw on my local machine. Otherwise sshuttle was erroring out.

So, on local machine, I did:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Then,

```
sshuttle -r username@ipForSubnetA 0.0.0.0/0 -vv --dns
```

This actually (scarily?) allowed me to on my local machine access elements of subnet B.

The remote machine is quite locked down firewall-wise, only allowing SSH access via private key over one port.

If anyone knows any insecurities in sshuttle please feel free to tell me :)